# Setting div width as % with min-width is not working. Min-width always wins.

Tags: html, width, aspect-ratio, css

I am having an issue with my width: 20%; being overridden by my min-width: 30px; (see lines 22 and 23 in the css box: http://jsfiddle.net/dLmnX/)

I am also using aspect ratio for the first time: I have picked up and chopped about the code from http://ansciath.tumblr.com/post/7347495869/css-aspect-ratio.

The aspect ratio part of the code:

```
  #aspect {
      padding-top: 120%; /* aspect ratio */
  }
```

seems to be working fine, it is just the width in this div:

```
  #shuffle1 {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 20%;
    min-width: 30px;        
  }
```

Any help would be great!
Thank you.

Comment: You are using div id `#shuffle1` too many times. Change to class instead `.shuffle1`

Comment: An `id` (`#idName`) must be unique for the current HTML document, while a `class` (`.className`) can be reused as many times as you'd like.  Both `#shuffle1` and `#two` are used multiple times, which is not allowed.

Comment: Thanks! Is it just bad practice? Or does it effect the outcome of the page?

Comment: It makes the document invalid.  It doesn't impact the CSS, but it would cause a lot of confusion if you were using the ids as a hook for JavaScript (eg. `document.getElementById('two')` -- which would it select?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit is the styling for the `#two` element.

http://jsfiddle.net/dLmnX/2/

```
  #two {
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

When you specify width as a percentage, it is relative to the size of the parent element.  Because `#two` was very small, there was no way that 20% would ever be larger than 30px.  Elements set to inline-block will try to take up as little space as possible.

Comment: OMG StackOverflow is awesome. Thanks very much!

Comment: Also, how did you know the #two was very small? I thought if I had a div and did not specify the width or height it would not effect the size of anything within it. Is this not correct?

Comment: I knew `#two` was small because its children were small, and its children have a width defined in percentages.  I could have just used the DOM inspector in my browser as well.  How wide an element will be when a width is unspecified depends on the display type.  Like I said, an element that is `inline-block` will try to take up as little horizontal space as possible.